# Get Text (plain String) from AttributedString -- how to do, and why so hard?

Tags: java, string

I can create an `AttributedString` like so:

```
AttributedString as = new AttributedString("Hello world");
```

Straightforward question -- how can I get the underlying text ("Hello world") from the AttributedString object?

`as.toString()` produces the string "java.text.AttributedString@65f00565"

I see in `AttributedString.class` that this information is stored, but deliberately private--

> all (with the exception of length) reading operations are private,
>   since AttributedString instances are accessed through iterator

So looks like I need to use `as.getIterator()` to get an `AttributedCharacterIterator` and iterate over it to produce the underlying string ? Is this the best approach, and why this information is so inaccessible?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @AJPerez , thanks for the tip, tag removed.

Comment: @biziclop , I have a rendering method that takes in an AttributedString, but I need information about the underlying string as well. It seems silly to require both a String and an AttributedString as parameters...?

Comment: Well just pass the String then and create the AttributedString within the method itself...?

Comment: @StuBlair Unless you can construct the `AttributedString` from the `String` in your method, there's no other option than the two you listed: get the iterator or ask for the string in advance. Both are quite awful but then `AttributedString` is a truly awful class.

Comment: @bwa, the AttributedString contains important formatting information that is determined outside of the scope of the method.

Comment: @bwa I suppose attributes have already been set by this time, so constructing it from the string alone may not be an option.

Comment: @StuBlair Here's something you could do to avoid some of the nastiness: you can create a class that wraps an `AttributedString` and the raw string. You set all the attributes on this composite (which delegates the calls to the wrapped `AttributedString`) and you pass this composite around rather than the underlying horror.

Comment: @biziclop, I like that. Thanks for thinking this through with me.

Comment: Also known as Sweeping It Under The Carpet pattern :) Or Quarantine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is the actual code to do what you're asking:

```
    AttributedString s = new AttributedString("Hello");
    AttributedCharacterIterator x = s.getIterator();
    String a = "";

    a+=x.current();
    while (x.getIndex() < x.getEndIndex())
        a += x.next();
    a=a.substring(0,a.length()-1);

    System.out.println(a);
```

As for the appropriateness, I defer to the documentation for `AttributedString`, specifically the `getIterator()` method:

> Creates an AttributedCharacterIterator instance that provides access to the entire contents of this string.

There appears to be no other way to access the actual `String` contents.

Comment: An unfortunate reality, but you actually answered the question, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getString(AttributedString attributedString){
        AttributedCharacterIterator it = attributedString.getIterator();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        char ch = it.current();
        while( ch != CharacterIterator.DONE)
        {
            stringBuilder.append( ch);
            ch = it.next();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```